# Compare three different array and arrange them in same order

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to arrange three different arrays in the same order, all three arrays as same size but values are not in the same order. How can I arrange them into the same order?

First array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [id] => 1 )
    [1] => Array( [id] => 12 )
    [2] => Array( [id] => 25 )
    [3] => Array( [id] => 54 )
)
```

Second array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [id] => 24 )
    [1] => Array( [id] => 12 )
    [2] => Array( [id] => 54 )
    [3] => Array( [id] => 1 )
)
```

Third array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [id] => 54 )
    [1] => Array( [id] => 25 )
    [2] => Array( [id] => 1 )
    [3] => Array( [id] => 12 )
)
```

Expected final array result:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array( [id] => 1 )
    [1] => Array( [id] => 12 )
    [2] => Array( [id] => 25 )
    [3] => Array( [id] => 54 )
)
```

All three arrays are arranged like the first array. I tried a lot but it's not working.

Comment: `i tried lot` Where is your code?

Comment: Why you need the same array 3 times ?

Comment: *all three arrays are arrange like first array* `$arr3 = $arr2 = $arr1`

Answer (score 0):

As you want the result to be in the order of the first array, try multisort the arrays with the first array
array_multisort($arr2,$arrone);
array_multisort($arr3,$arrone);

Answer (score 0):

To get all arrays arranged in the same way as a given reference array you can use a custom search function for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function orderarrayByReferencearrayIds(array $referencearray, array $arrayToSort) {
    // get an array with the id order of the reference array
    $idOrder = array_column($referencearray, 'id');

    usort($arrayToSort, function (array $a, array $b) use ($idOrder) {
        // get the index in reference sort order of each element
        $aIndex = array_search($a['id'], $idOrder);
        $bIndex = array_search($b['id'], $idOrder);

        return $aIndex - $bIndex;
    });

    return $arrayToSort;
}
```

This doesn't work for your second array as the id '24' is not present in the reference array.